# Updating foreign key field in SQLite using ContentValues and update()

Tags: sqlite

I am having trouble getting a foreign key to update in a SQLite table that's running in my Android app.

I have two tables, CASHFLOW_TABLE and ACCOUNT_TABLE.  CASHFLOW_TABLE has a foreign key column that references the _id column of ACCOUNT_TABLE.  I want to update values in one line of CASHFLOW_TABLE, but when I run this code

```
String where = "_id=?";
String[] whereArgs = {"7"};

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put(CF_COL_PURPOSE, "Coffee");
cv.put(CF_COL_VALUE, 2.5);
cv.put(CF_COL_ACCOUNT_ID, 4);

myDatabase.update(CF_TABLE_NAME, cv, where, whereArgs);
```

I receive the error message:

E/Database(22962): Error updating ACCOUNT_ID=4 VALUE=2.5 PURPOSE=Coffee using UPDATE CASHFLOW_TABLE SET ACCOUNT_ID=?, VALUE=?, PURPOSE=? WHERE _id=?

The reason I think this has something to do with the fact that CF_COL_ACCOUNT_ID is a foreign key is that when I remove

```
    cv.put(CF_COL_ACCOUNT_ID, 4);
```

and run the code just to update just the other values, it works fine.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Update: when I try to run the update as an SQL statement, I get the following error, which does seem to suggest that the problem is with the foreign key constraint:

E/Database(24650): Failure 19 (foreign key constraint failed) on 0x314530 when executing 'update CASHFLOW_TABLE set VALUE= 2.5, PURPOSE='coffee', ACCOUNT_ID=4 where _id = 7'

Below is the code in onCreate() that sets up the tables and foreign key constraint.  I have simplified it a bit here--there are other columns and one other foreign key (for a third table not shown here).

```
db.execSQL("Create table " + A_TABLE_NAME + " (" + A_COL_ID             + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + A_COL_NAME
+ " text default ('" + A_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT + "'));");

db.execSQL("Create table " + CF_TABLE_NAME + " (" + CF_COL_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + CF_COL_VALUE
      + " real not null, "
      + CF_COL_PURPOSE + " text not null, " + CF_COL_TIMESTAMP
      + " text not null default (strftime('%s','now')), "
      + CF_COL_ACCOUNT_ID
      + " integer not null default 1, foreign key ("
      + CF_COL_ACCOUNT_ID + ") references " + A_TABLE_NAME + " ("
      + A_COL_ID + ") on delete set default);");
```

Comment: Are you sure there's actually a row in **ACCOUNT_TABLE** with id of 4?

Comment: That would be the first thing to check, because if a foreign key references a non-existent primary key, then the insert will fail.

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to be the problem--there are matching records in the parent field.  I get a different error message when I use SQL rather than update() to make the update (I added the new error to my question above), which suggests this is a problem with my foreign key.

Comment: Please include the third table and if possible the un-simplified form.

Comment: Sorry, dbaseman was right after all.  I had been auto-entering a bunch of sample records to work in the onCreate() with and gave zero as the account_id value for all of the records.  There was no record with zero as the _id value in the accounts table.  When I went to update the records, this seems to have been what caused the error.  I don't understand why it was letting me enter in these zero values to begin with, though, since it seems like they should made the foreign key constraint fail.